# How can I invoke custom path index html from spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss

While hitting the url it throws

11:13:11,515 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-1) Cannot forward to error page for request [/resources/build/index.html] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false: java.io.IOException: UT010029: Stream is closed

Comment: My Index.html is located at src/main/webapp/resources/build/

Comment: My url is localhost:8080/AlumniPortal/ while hitting the url output was came but as well as the above error throws